How does pyarrow handles date partitions?
I store files on s3 in the following format:
../country/state/city/date=2024-08-02/12-00-57/time_series.parquet
and the table contains multiple columns on of which is named date of type pa.date64(). So far so good. The issue arises when I try to read that file using pandas (and pyarrow). When I downgrade to pyarrow <17x I can see all of the different dates of my table.
On previous versions of pyarrow (<17x) I was able to read the files correctly. On the latest version, however, when I read the file each row of the table has the same date and that date is the date listed in the filename partition (in this example the date on every row is 2024-08-02. Note that I have the same issue when I provide the table schema on the pandas read_parquet file.
I wasn't able to find any release notes about that, I much appreciate any help.

Please give the commands you've tried using.
